# Chrome does not honor table width setting using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, css

Chrome doesn't seem to honor the .width() setting that I set on a table.  IE10 does.

I get the width of the table after the page is done loading: 425px.
Then I remove the row with the widest content, which makes the table repaint and the table's width shrinks: 185px.

Then, I set the table's width to the original value, 425px.  But if I  check the width of the table after the set, it is off (by 2px in my experiments): 423px.

Is this a known bug?

Am I using the wrong get/set?

It seems that it has to do with the table border (1px border X2 = 2px), but do I need to do calculations to account for the border when setting the width?

I have a jsfiddle that replicates the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/slolife/zLyQ2/

```
var orgWidth = $('table').width();
alert('Original width = ' + orgWidth);
$('table').width(orgWidth);
alert('Width after setting width to ' + orgWidth + ' = ' + $('table').width());
$('#two').remove();
alert('Width after remove = ' + $('table').width());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about the [box model.](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html)

add

```
table{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The link is a very interesting read but basically you force calculation including borders and padding which is not compatible with w3c spec.

updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLyQ2/7/)